# NSMutableDictionary and Caching to Disk

Tags: xcode, caching, optimization, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to optimize my application as much as I can. All I am asking is "NSMutableDictionary after you add an object for a certain key, Does it store the data in the ram memory or the storage memory?" I am using Xcode 4.5.2 with iOS 6.0 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only storing a pointer -- a reference to an object. That pointer is stored in memory. When added, `NSMutableDictionary` does not do anything special -- e.g. message the values to somehow minimize their physical memory consumption.

If you want values saved to disk or to support purging, see `NSCache`. It may be exactly what you are looking for.

Otherwise, you may favor just writing to disk, and storing `NSURL`s in the dictionary. Hard to say, not knowing how you are approaching this optimization.

Comment: I am trying to make my application to not use too much ram memory, so I was trying to find is that NSMutableDictionary is storing its data in the storage memory until the app is terminated or closed

Comment: @AhmedHossny In that case, I'd recommend minimizing your memory consumption/references/leaks/cyclic references/etc where possible, before writing a disk based implementation.

Comment: NSCache isn't save data to disk.